Stochastic Simulation - Simulation from the Marginal Distributions
I am reviewing some material on MCMC / simulation and I realised I never quite understood this point. Given a joint distribution $f(x_1, ..., x_n) = f(x_1) f(x_2 | x_1)...f(x_n | x_{n-1}, ..., x_1)$ if we want to simulate values from this joint density (assuming we can) then we can simulate
$$
\begin{align}
& x_1^{(1)} \text{ from } f(x_1)\\\\
& x_2^{(1)} \text{ from } f(x_2 | x_1)\\\\
& x_n^{(1)} \text{ from } f(x_n | x_{n-1}, ..., x_1)
\end{align}
$$
In the case of a Markov Chain, this simplifies to sampling from $f(x_{t+1} | x_t)$. The book goes on to say that the each of the sample values are sampled from the marginal distribution of $x_j$ which I fail to see for all but $x_1$, since for $j > 1, x_j$ is sampled from the conditional distribution $f(x_j | x_{j-1})$
This book is from a course from the university so I cannot direct you to it but I wondered if someone could help me better understand what the book means.
Thanks a lot in advance!
Update
I have added a snip of the passage from the book below for reference. Just below the final bullet point it states that "... What's more, $x_1^{(1)}$ is a simulated value from the marginal $f(x_1)$, $x_2^{(1)}$ is a simulated value from the marginal $f(x_2)$, and so on"
As mentioned, $x_1^{(1)}$ makes sense but for $x_2^{(1)}$ this does not. Hope this adds some clarification.


I guess the Markov chain is not running on the space of $x$, but on some larger one. It is a common practice to run MCMC on a larger space $(x,\theta)$, where $\theta$ is an auxiliary variable to accelerate mixing. In these situations, we might say the Markov chain samples from the marginal distribution (on the larger space).

My guess would be that there is, possibly, some fundamental misunderstanding how the material. Could you maybe take a step back and give the context of your question (in terms of what algorithm we are building, to achieve what?)

If the book says such conditional distribution is marginal, then it is wrong.

Thank you both. Please see my edit to the question where I have added a snip of the passage where this is referenced.
